# Inferring a type from Entity fields

Tags: typescript, nestjs, typeorm

For querying the db, in different **.repository.ts** files, for the **find** method, I use pretty much the same configuration object that looks like this:

```
const findOptions = {
  ...(search && {
    where: { name: ILike(`%${search}%`) },
  }),
};
```

and then `await this.find(findOptions)`

I want to extract a general type for this object, and for the one above, it's pretty simple and I use:

```
import { FindOperator } from 'typeorm';

interface FindOptions {
  where: {
    name: FindOperator<string>;
  };
}
```

But there are some places where the **findOptions** object has additional properties tied to it, based on relation with another enitity like so:

```
const findOptions: FindOptions = {
  relations: ['entityName'],
  ...(search && {
    where: { name: ILike(`%${search}%`) },
  }),
  ...(idArray && {
    where: {
      entityName: {
        id: In(idArray),
      },
      ...(search && {
        name: ILike(`%${search}%`),
      }),
    },
  }),
};
```

Notice here the **entityName**

The above type for **findOptions** object would be:

```
import { FindOperator } from 'typeorm';

interface FindOptions {
  where: {
    name: FindOperator<string>;
    entityName: {
      id: FindOperator<string>;
    };
  };
  relations: string[];
}
```

Is there a way to make **FindOptions interface** more general, based on the relations the entity has with other entities? I'm talking about not explicitly mentioning entityName, but inferring a general type. Something like:

```
import { FindOperator } from 'typeorm';

interface FindOptions<T> {
  where: {
    name: FindOperator<string>;
    [P in keyof T]: {
      id: FindOperator<string>;
    };
  };
  relations: string[];
}
```

where T is the entity:

```
@Entity({ name: 'myEntity' })
export class MyEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string;

  @Column({ type: 'varchar' })
  name: string;

  @ManyToOne(() => AnotherEntity)
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'anotherEntityId', referencedColumnName: 'id' })
  anotherEntity: AnotherEntity;
}
```

and ideally **entityName** would be replaced by **anotherEntity**

Comment: Do you get any error with the code you illustrated in the question?

Comment: @msrumon several actually:
Member '[P in keyof' implicitly has an 'any' type, but a better type may be inferred from usage;
Cannot find name 'P';
Cannot find name 'T'

Comment: You're going through the indices of `T` with `P` but you ain't using it anywhere. Hence `cannot find P` error. The 3rd error indicates you probably haven't passed in `T` when you've used `FindOptions` generic. When you use it like `FindOptions<MyEntity>`, both 1st and 3rd errors should go away.

Comment: @msrumon I don't get it. I've written FindOptions<MyEntity> and also 

interface FindOptions<T> {
  where: {
    name: FindOperator<string>;
    [P in keyof T]: {
      id: FindOperator<string>;
    };
  };
  relations: string[];
} 
and it don't work